# C# Winfoms: Datagridview row back colour based on Combobox result

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a curious problem that I have not been able to find a solution for.

I have a datagridview with many rows and columns. One column contains a dropdown datagridviewcombobox which contains various colours to choose from.

[image]

I have an event which listens for the combobox value changing, all working correctly, in that event I call this piece of code which should set the datagridviewrow's back colour to the ARGB value returned. However, the rows back colour is not set, instead the combobox cell's back colour is coloured instead.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rowNo].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Processing.returnARGBColour(colourName));
```

[image]

Why is this happening and what can be done to colour the datagridview row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 dataGridView1.Rows[rowNo].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Yes that did work as expected. I have since changed from using ARGB to converting from HTML using colorTranslator which works perfect. I wondered if there was an error in the alpha part of the argb code that i return but if the code works and sets the correct colour for the combobox then it should have worked for the datagridview row...